# Can emails be recovered on Iphone 5s?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to recover emails from an iPhone 5s that completely disappeared the other day? It is through Outlook Express, have AT&T and it is IOS 7.0.1 version. They were not deleted. I was on my phone back and forth from facebook to email to safari and the "manage your storage" message kept popping up. A couple hours earlier, I had deleted some photos from photo roll and text messages to make more room and I was also deleting unwanted emails thinking that would help (which upon further investigation it does not) because I knew my storage was low. I had deleted like almost 2000 emails from Hotmail earlier and I think later when I went into Hotmail it picked up other emails that must have been "hanging" out there and when there was room they started updating or downloading but it was when I went into outlook later that 850 emails just disappeared. They are not in trash. I looked into all those iPhone recovery downloads but it doesn't look like they can get emails back. Would iTunes backup work somehow?! Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Did you download Outlook for iOS or were you using Outlook Express on a Windows machine? When you say you were in Hotmail you mean you were on outlook.com? Or do you mean you had your account configured on your phone on the Mail app? Thanks

Comment: I have two email accounts in my iPhone. one is through outlook and the other is Hotmail.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean exactly when you say "through outlook"? Is it an Exchange account? Do you have the Outlook for iOS installed and look at it on your iPhone? Is it an outlook.com account?

Comment: I have it on my ipone but I don't think I have an app. its just there in my mail acct. there is no archive folder and they are not in the trash

Comment: If it was configured as a POP account, when deleted from the client, mails are gone -if not in the trash. If it was configured as an IMAP account, they may be on the server trash: try to access a web based version of your mail (probably at outlook.com). Anyway, there usually is a mirror trash on your client, so if they are not there it's not likely that they will be on the server. If you have a backup on iTunes, and the account was configured as POP, you may be able to recover your mail, along with everything else. You will lose changes made between the last backup and the restoration date.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find your archive folder, the emails should be in there and once you find them they can be moved to your inbox.